# A compact set in the plane with small sum-set and large projections

Tags: gn.general-topology, plane-geometry

**Problem.** Let $K$ be a compact subset of the plane such that the projection of $K$ on each line has non-empty interior in the line. Has $K+K$ or $K-K$  non-empty interior in the plane?

**Remark.** The results of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.01997) imply the affirmative answer to this problem  for compact subsets $K$ of positive dimension in the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. The key point is the following

**Lemma:** For every $L>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R^2, x\ne 0$, there exist $\ell>0$ and a closed origin-symmetric set $F\subset\mathbb R^2$ such that every interval $I$ of length $L$ on the plane contains a subinterval $J\subset I\cap F$ of length $\ell$ while $F\cap(F+x)=\varnothing$.

**Proof:** WLOG, $x=(0,1)$. Now choose a huge integer $N=N(L)$ and consider the sinusoidal strip $S=\{(x,y):|y-\sin x|\le\frac 1{10(2N+1)}\}$. Take $F=\cup_{k\in\mathbb Z}(S+(0,\frac{2k}{2N+1}))$.

Now just enumerate some dense set $x_1,x_2,\dots$ on the plane, take $L_1=1$ and use $x_k$ and $L_k$ to construct $F_k$ and $L_{k+1}$. Put $K=\cap_k F_k\cap \bar D(0,10)$, say (note that each finite intersection of $F_k$ intersects every interval of length $1$, so this property will survive for the full intersection $\cap_k F_k$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, this problem (repeated in one my paper with coauthors) has been resolved by Balka, Elekes, Kiss, Nagy, Poor in 2020, see (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.15206.pdf).

Comment: @TarasBanakh Indeed, but I still surmise that for this particular case (two summands), my construction is somewhat simpler :lol:. Needless to say, it works in any dimension too: all you need is an origin-symmetric surface containing no straight line segment instead of the $\sin$ curve. $K+K+K$ is more interesting, though; I agree here.